# CefSharp execute javascript and get value

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp and an HTML editor loaded from a html file. I got the javascript code to get the contents of the html editor:

```
var markupStr = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
```

I need `markupStr` in my C# application returned. What I currently have:

```
 var script = "$('#summernote').summernote('code');";
 var result = ChromiumWebBrowser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(script).Result.Message;
```

I can execute JavaScript in CefSharp effortlessly, however, how do I retrieve `markupStr` or its value set by `$('#summernote').summernote('code');`?

Comment: You need to wait for the task to complete before you can access the result. Also message is the error message, look at the examples on the FAQ

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume that you script variable looks like this (or smth like this):

```
var myScript = @"(function () {
    return $('#summernote').summernote('code').val();
})();";
```

What means that the return value type is `string`.

Then you do a simple operation

```
var result = await myBrowserVariable.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(myScript)
.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    var result = t.Result;
    return (string)result;
});
```

Now 'result' variable contains result of `myScript` javascript method execution.
Also, please do not forget to add null check (because `t.Result` can be null) and call `EvaluateScriptAsync` method only when current frame is already loaded.